# Command line git commands suddenly asking for password

Tags: git, macos, macos-monterey

For the last three weeks I have been using the OSX keychain to manage my GitHub credentials.  Whenever I need to pull in an update, I do the usual:

```
git pull origin master
```

With this command, the keychain then pops up and requests my password, which I type, and then the command that was entered in the command line executes.

Suddenly this morning, I go to pull in another change, and it now asks in the command line for my user name and password.  Then I get the usual error:

```
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
```

I have worked on this for some time and don't get why the methods in other questions aren't working.  I have followed these other posts with no luck

[osxkeychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38979625/git-osxkeychain-credential-helper-silently-fails-to-remember-username-password)

[update git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661354/github-for-mac-error-git-credential-osxkeychain-is-not-a-git-command/55060030)

[credential helper and ssh-add -L answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773181/git-keeps-prompting-me-for-a-password)

Comment: You need to use a personal access token instead of your password when asked for your password.

Comment: @bk2204 thanks, it was the use of the term "password" in lieu of "personal access token" that threw me off!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this has nothing to do with `ssh-add`, used to cache private SSH key *passphrase*.

Second, this has to do with [GitHub new policy: Git password authentication is shutting down](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-08-12-git-password-authentication-is-shutting-down/).

You need to use a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) instead of your GitHub account password, as described in "[Dealing With GitHub Password Authentication Deprecation](https://betterprogramming.pub/dealing-with-github-password-authentication-deprecation-1b59ced90065)" by **[Antonello Zanini](https://antonellozanini.com/)**, and [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70193715/6309).

Comment: thank you very much!  I think it was separating some of these concepts that helped.  If anyone else stumbles across this, when the command line asks for your password, you instead provide the personal access token, as VonC said.  That overlap of the names password/PAT threw me off.